# In using Vuforia SDK for Android, on running VideoPlayback I get the error

Tags: android

on Running VideoPlayback I get the error as java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: setActivityPortraitMode, can anyone help to get solved on this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First excecute ndk-build then import your app and run

Comment: its ok,me too working i have so many doubts in that,follow this forum its useful for you https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/android-how-do-i-add-another-target-video-playback-sample